# run-time error '1004': method 'range' of object '_global' failed for method that works error-free in another context

Tags: vba, excel

I have an issue with the following lines giving me the run-time error referenced in the title, with the first line of the if statement being highlighted as the culprit:

```
Sub setupFirstWorksheet()
    For i = 0 To Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.Count
        If Range("h" & i).Value = 1010 Or Range("j" & i).Value < 0 Or Range("k" & i).Value = False Then
           [some code or blank]
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

However, putting in similar code below, I have no issues:

```
Sub test()
    For i = 0 To Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.Count
    Next i
    MsgBox Range("h" & i).Value
End Sub
```

Any help with this would be much appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are starting your loop at 0, which means you are generating range references H0,J0 & K0. These are invalid because there is no such thing as row 0.

Change your loop to start at 1 and you will be okay.

The reason your test works is because your MsgBox line is only executed after the loop has finished, and i will equal `Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.Count`. If you move the MsgBox statement into the loop, you will find that it will also fail.